# Using GROUP BY aggregating SUM on a calculated column

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I tried asking this question earlier and now I found a more consolidated way of asking this question.

I'm working in Access 2007.

I have a query of the following format in Access:

```
SELECT RecDate, Weight * YTD / (SELECT SUM(Weight) From Records 
WHERE Class1=t2.Class1 AND Class2 = t2.Class2) as AdjYield
From Records as t2
WHERE Class1="fi" AND Class2="ra"
```

It gives me the following result

```
RecDate AdjYield
11/27/2012  4.73704622309864E-05
11/27/2012  0
11/27/2012  -1.87533613791046E-04
11/27/2012  -2.4014644030909E-05
11/27/2012  1.29986083977377E-04
11/27/2012  1.2765190817936E-04
12/11/2012  1.10288780895771E-04
12/11/2012  0
12/11/2012  -1.7463943470934E-04
12/11/2012  -1.51778890534467E-05
12/11/2012  1.47374111584102E-04
12/11/2012  1.45120288096115E-04
```

Now I want the SUM of each day's calculated AdjYield

```
RecDate AdJYield
11/27/2012, 1.557E-05
12/11/2012, 3.549E-05
```

I tried putting SUM() around the `Weight * YTD / (SELECT SUM(Weight) From Records WHERE Class1=t2.Class1 AND Class2 = t2.Class2) as AdjYield` part and then adding `GROUP BY RecDate` in the end. However I get an error saying

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression "Class1" as part of an aggregate function.

Any idea on how to do this aggregate correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your existing query as a subquery in another where you `GROUP BY RecDate`.

```
SELECT sub.RecDate, Sum(sub.AdjYield) AS SumOfAdjYield
FROM
    (
        SELECT RecDate, Weight * YTD / (SELECT SUM(Weight) From Records 
        WHERE Class1=t2.Class1 AND Class2 = t2.Class2) as AdjYield
        From Records as t2
        WHERE Class1="fi" AND Class2="ra"
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.RecDate;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. I knew there's another subquery in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one table with these fields : RecDate AdjYield in a table called records, you

```
should be able to say
SELECT SUM(AdjYield)
FROM Records
Group by RecDate
```

If that is not the case, please clarify.

Comment: This is a workaround but I'm trying to consolidate it into one query.